# having problems to import javax.servelt

Tags: java

I am trying to import this package (javax.servelet.*;) but netbeans is saying that the package does not exist. Does anyone know what might be the problem?
Thx.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you've misspelt it. It's

```
javax.servlet.*;
```

If it still can't be found, then make sure the servlet-api.jar is on your classpath.

Comment: Could you please explain how can it be checked?

Comment: Netbeans telling you the package does not exist was it being checked. You could have also typed javax. and then waited for the IDE to present you with a list of packages and selected the appropriate one from the context list.

Comment: Looks like I will need to install an earlier version of netbeans that supports the feature I am trying to use....

Comment: The JAR isn't necessarily called `servlet-api.jar`. This one is Tomcat-specific. In Glassfish for example, which usually get bundled with Netbeans, it's `javaee.jar`. Regardless, you shouldn't add loose JAR files to the build path. I don't do Netbeans, but in a normal IDE like Eclipse/IntelliJ, all you need to do is to integrate the server in the IDE and associate the web project with it. The IDE will handle it automagically then.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I will need to install an earlier version of netbeans that supports the feature I am trying to use....